# MySQL joins - make sure one record is always found

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a MySQL-query to return some activities on a city's page based on to parameters:

- The city's shorttag
- The chosem CategoryID's

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT
                a.ActivityID as ActivityID,
                a.Name as ActivityName,
                a.Description as ActivityDescription,
                a.Address as ActivityAddress,
                a.Mail as ActivityMail,
                a.Shorttag as ActivityShorttag,
                a.Phone as ActivityPhone,
                (SELECT ap.ThumbPath FROM ActivityPictures ap WHERE Acti_ActivityID = a.ActivityID ORDER BY MainPicture DESC, PictureID ASC LIMIT 1) as ActivityThumbPath,
                c.CityID as CityID,
                c.Name as CityName,
                c.PostalCode as CityPostalCode,
                c.Shorttag as CityShorttag,
                c.ShortDescription as CategoryShortDescription,
                c.LongDescription as CategoryLongDescription,
                ca.CategoryID as CategoryID
            FROM
                Cities c
            LEFT JOIN
                Activities a
                ON
                    c.CityID = a.City_CityID
            LEFT JOIN
                ActivityCategoryConn acc
                ON
                    a.ActivityID = acc.Acti_ActivityID
            LEFT JOIN
                Categories ca
                ON
                    acc.Cate_CategoryID = ca.CategoryID
                    AND
                    ca.CategoryID IN (2)
            WHERE
                c.Shorttag = 'city-shorttag'
            ORDER BY
                a.ActivityID desc
```

I want this to ALWAYS  return at least one row with the info from "Cities c" - but if no activities are matching the CategoryID, the rest can just be NULL. If there is Activities these should of course return the number of rows matching.

How can I make this query ALWAYS return at least one record containing c.* - even if the array in the "IN"-statement doesnt contain a matched CategoryID?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I make this query ALWAYS return at least one record containing c.* - even if the array in the "IN"-statement doesnt contain a matched CategoryID?

Comment: Couldn't understand your completely, but, I guess you are trying to solve your programming problem in MySQL query. I'll recommend that you should execute two or three queries according to your need and process the results to produce actual result.

Answer (score 0):

You can fall back to a null by ORing with a IS NULL statement

```
AND
(
  ca.CategoryID IN (2)
  OR
  ca.CategoryID IS NULL
)
```